# Php non-numeric value encounted warning

Tags: php

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/students/vt20/ai0010/public_html/Prog1/rep uppgifter/uppgift 14.php on line 16 which is

```
$summa = $summa + $row[ $i ];
```

How do I remove it

```
$summa = 0;

$row   = explode( "@", file_get_contents( 'slump.txt'));

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $row ); $i ++ ) {
        $summa = $summa + $row[ $i ];
    }
    echo "Summan av talen i filen är: " . $summa;
```

Comment: just `var_dump($row )` and see if anything is non-numeric.

Comment: or can you show the contents of `slump.txt`.  Also you should look at `array_sum()` if it's just a list of number in `$row`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$summa = 0;
$row   = explode( "@", file_get_contents( 'slump.txt'));

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $row ) - 1; $i++ ) {
    $summa = $summa + $row[ $i ];
}

echo "Summan av talen i filen är: " . $summa;
```

For anyone wondering about this problem, I solved it, in the last position of my slump.txt file, was empty, therefore it became non-numeric. I put -1 on my for loop to not include last position in my file.